# HTML Microdata using tags more than once

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I was wondering if using the same microdata tags on the same page of a website is 'valid'. For example I have a standard footer which contains the address of the company and I have a contact us page which also has the company address on.

I was wondering if using the Organisation tag on both of these for the address is 'valid'?
Or should I just tag the footer?

Comment: Ehm... "Organization tag"? I hope you don't mean what I fear you mean.

Comment: Well not organization tag as such, something more like
`<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">`

Comment: @LukeCheerfulPlumPace: I misread your question at first. I just updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18685050/1591669).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http://schema.org/Organization` (or any other item type) on any page, as Microdata markup is per page, not per site. Microdata and/or schema.org have no concept of "website". Each webpage is stand-alone as far as the name-value pairs are concerned.

If you use `http://schema.org/Organization` several times on the *same* page, you are essentially creating several organizations. In some cases this is what you want (e.g. when you list different organizations on the same page), but in your case this is not what you want to achieve (as it’s about the same organization).

So you should only markup **one** of those addresses.

If one of the two snippets contains information about the organization which the other one doesn’t give, you could use [`itemref`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52592/17633) to relate these together.